# How can I wait for JSONP callback?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I am working on Flightstats api and I want to wait for callback from JSONP to pick up only "AA" flights for example from a certain date. 
Because Flightstats api allow to be requested only for one hour at one request, I have to make 24 requests at the same time. 
Thanks for your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

var scheduledFlightsArray = new Array();    

for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    var src = "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/jsonp/from/KSFO/departing/2014/12/5/" + i + "?appId=*****&appKey=*****";

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function callback(data)
{   
    var scheduledFlights = data.scheduledFlights;

    for (var i = 0; i < scheduledFlights.length; i++)
    {
        if (scheduledFlights[i].carrierFsCode == "AA" && !scheduledFlights[i].operator)
        {   
            scheduledFlightsArray.push(scheduledFlights[i]);
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < scheduledFlightsArray.length; i++)
{
    console.log(scheduledFlightsArray[i].carrierFsCode + scheduledFlightsArray[i].flightNumber);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Keep a counter how often `callback` was called. If it was called as many times as requests you have, continue processing the data.

Comment: Thanks. I knew callback are coming, but I wanted to stop program till the last callback comes. Now I solved this issue by myself. I put 'count++' in my callback() and 'if (count == 24){do something}'.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Now I understood, yes you meant it. Sorry.